# how to run other gradle command in the gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have two module, app and module1

app is not dependency module1

module1 assembleRelease task will change data in app

so,I want to run module1:assembleRelease automatically when I run app:assembleRelease.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ....

    afterEvaluate {
        preBuild.dependsOn({
            runModuleaR.execute()
        })
    }
}

task runModuleaR(type: Exec) {
    println "runModuleaR start"
    commandLine "cmd", "gradlew", ':module1:assembleRelease'
    println "runModuleaR finish"
}
```

is my build.gradle

But it has no effect

How do I change it?Thanks